# How to get a post variable <button type="button"> submitted by .submit()

Tags: javascript

```js
<script>
    function submittheform(){
        document.forms['form_id'].submit();
    }
</script>
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="form_id" action="#">
    <input type="text" id="lan" value="" name="number"/>
    <button type="button" onclick="submittheform()" value="submit the form"/>
</form>
</body>
```

I want to get the post variable in php. How to do it?

Comment: Only in JavaScript or any server side language?

Comment: What's your purpose? to collecting the form data and submit it?

Comment: I want the submit the form onbutton click event and want to get  the post  variable in the same page with php

Comment: Why don't you just use a real submit button?

Comment: real submit button gets resubmitted again and again.

Comment: ... what? Please explain what you're talking about.

Comment: I made ajax request based on the button click. But using  real submit button, it is  resubmitted again and again.

Comment: Why did you make an AJAX request?!

Comment: @MD.NoorUddin use event.prevent default to prevent submitting again & again

Comment: I made a simple price comparison website by web scrapping for which I made several ajax request and no php was there. Now I want to store users searching history in database.

Comment: You can simply use document.getElementById("Input_field") to get the value of any input field in any get or post method of form. why do you want to submit the form.

Comment: Now I have used real button and problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not possible** if you want to get data which was posted by form in JavaScript. Because JavaScript is browser oriented. You need any **server side language** like PHP if you want to get post data submitted by form.